# Customize Sequencejs sliders

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, slider

I've been working on the Sequence slider from [www.sequencejs.com](http://www.sequencejs.com). The slider is very intuitive  but it can only do one kind of animation on an object, from what i've observed so far, here's how the slider works:

1.the html section consist of an unordered list which in turn have list-items

2.the js file edits the li's class to "animate-in" marking the rest of them "animate-out"

3.after 5s, the second li is marked "animate-in" and rest are marked "animate-out"

4.the css file uses the css3 transitions to animate classes when "animate-in" is triggered on that class

**What i need?**
I need to do multiple animations on one object. But not together, rather one after another, for instance, an image would slide in from the right; then scale up.

Maybe there's some way of doing it that i might not know, i would appreciate your help with that
Or, I was thinking if the javascript file could add more classes at certain times, I could get the effect. I went through the javascript but I'm not skilled enough to understand that yet.
Could you guys take a look at it and explain me which parts handle the class changing? How can I make it add more classes between "animate-in" and "animate-out"?

You can get the slider from here: [sequencejs.com/slider-parallax/](http://www.sequencejs.com/themes/sliding-horizontal-parallax/)

Hope I was clear enough.